# How to install maven 3.8 and jdk 17 on ubuntu using vagrant

Tags: java, vagrant, devops, maven-3, ubuntu-18.04

As the titles says, I am triying to install maven 3.8 and jdk17 in a virtual machine using vagrant. This is what I have:

Vagrantfile:

...

```
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "vagrantScripts/jdk17.sh"
```

...

jdk17.sh:

```
#jdk17 installation

curl  -O https://download.oracle.com/java/17/latest/jdk-17_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
sudo tar -xvf jdk-17_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
sudo mv jdk-17.0.2 /opt/jdk17
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk17
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

#maven 3.8.5 installation
curl  -O https://dlcdn.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.8.5/binaries/apache-maven-3.8.5-bin.tar.gz
sudo tar -xvf apache-maven-3.8.5-bin.tar.gz
sudo mv apache-maven-3.8.5 /opt/maven
export M2_HOME=/opt/maven
export MAVEN_HOME=/opt/maven
export PATH=${M2_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
```

If I do line by line coding in the command shell of the VM, everything works fine, but when I try to automate the installation using provision, it just doesn't work.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: `installation using provision, it just doesn't work.` what does this mean? How does your Vagrantfile look like? How do you call Vagrant ? Which version of Vagrant do you use? Furthermore why not using ansible for installing software on the system ? Furhtermore for Maven you only need an entry in PATH variable no `M2_HOME` nor `MAVEN_HOME`... Also you have to make entries in the `.bashrc` (or in system `/etc/profiles.d/...` ) entry to activate the path for new logins etc...

Answer (score -2):

Install JAVA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk
```

Install Maven ( on Jenkins machine )

```
cd /tmp
sudo wget https://dlcdn.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.8.5/binaries/apache-maven-3.8.5-bin.tar.gz

cd /tmp 
sudo tar -xzf apache-maven-3.8.5-bin.tar.gz -C  /opt/
mv /opt/apache-maven-3.8.5 /opt/maven
```

Comment: 1) That installs OpenJDK Java 8, not (Oracle or OpenJDK) Java 17.  2) For OpenJDK Java 17, you don't need a ppa repo.  It is in the standard repo for all current Ubuntu repos: 18.04 (bionic), 20.04 (focal), 21.10 (impish), 22.04 (jammy), 22.10 (kinetic)

Comment: Don't use PPA's unless you have a very good reason to!  Also Maven is usually in a standard package too.

Comment: How does all this adress the "doing it in a Vagrant environment" part of the question ?